# How to create reusable templates for dependabot configurations?

Tags: dependabot

I have a C# project containing multiple assemblies with some node modules as dev dependencies.

Given this example dependabot.yml configuration file

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: 'npm'
    directory: '/'
    schedule:
      interval: 'weekly'
    labels:
      - 'dependencies'
    target-branch: 'dev'
    commit-message:
      prefix: 'deps'
    reviewers:
      - 'user1'
      - 'user2'
      - 'user3'

  - package-ecosystem: 'nuget'
    directory: '/MyCsharpProject/Assembly1'
    schedule:
      interval: 'weekly'
    labels:
      - 'dependencies'
    target-branch: 'dev'
    commit-message:
      prefix: 'deps'
    reviewers:
      - 'user1'
      - 'user2'
      - 'user3'
```

both configurations are almost the same. The only things that are different:

- the ecosystem
- the directory

is there a way I can create some templates? This is a pseudo implementation I'm looking for

```
version: 2
updates:
  - template
      name: 'my-template'
      schedule:
        interval: 'weekly'
      labels:
        - 'dependencies'
      target-branch: 'dev'
      commit-message:
        prefix: 'deps'
      reviewers:
        - 'user1'
        - 'user2'
        - 'user3'

  - package-ecosystem: 'npm'
    directory: '/'
    fill-from: 'my-template'

  - package-ecosystem: 'nuget'
    directory: '/MyCsharpProject/Assembly1'
    fill-from: 'my-template'
```

Currently my C# project has 8 assemblies and the configuration requires a lot of copy paste. It would be nice to make things reusable.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that the YAML Schema of the dependabot configuration file supports either;

- `- template`
- `name:`
- or `fill-from:`

[These are the official docs for dependabot configuration](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-dependencies-updated-automatically/configuration-options-for-dependency-updates#configuration-options-for-updates) and detail the allowed key/value pairs available for configuration.

Sadly it doesn't look like it will let you adhere to the DRY principle. ️

Answer (score 0):

You could get quite a lot of DRYness by using [YAML anchors and aliases](https://medium.com/@kinghuang/docker-compose-anchors-aliases-extensions-a1e4105d70bd) in your Dependabot configuration, if Dependabot supported aliases and anvhors.

Sadly, it doesn't yet: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/1582 and it seems somewhat unlikely that it will be added any time in the near future.